# Importing a simple SVG logo from Inkscape into Blender and converting to mesh turns messy: zigzag lines going across the surface

Tags: mesh, svg

I wanted to convert this path to mesh to extrude it and make it 3D. The resulting mesh is a mess when i look at it in edit mode. Check my screenshots. How could i avoid all those zigzags across the surface and make this mesh something like the origin path?

The original SVG file is there: https://github.com/SebastJava/linuxmint-logo/blob/master/linuxmint-logo2-simple-0marg-00E000.svg This is just one single closed 25 nodes path without any zigzag lines going across...

In Blender, I did:
File > Import > SVG (and re-scaled)
and then: Right-click to convert to mesh, and the result is a mess:

[image: SVG path converted to mesh is messy]

EDIT: My logo does not have anything special or tricky. I tested a pure simple circle made in Inkscape and imported into Blender: same bad results at first, and same 5 seconds quick fix.

Comment: Hi, and welcome Check out [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/126273/35559). This Q. may wind up considered a duplicate.. but sure, the other versions are hard to hunt down.

Comment: Thanks!
"A typical good first move is X > Limited Dissolve.. before extrusion." solved it perfectly, at first try. But i still don't understand why i had to apply this fix...

Comment: You can also try a Decimate Modifier set to "Planar"

Comment: Thanks! This works too.

Comment: The reason.. (IMO) if the conversion _Limited Dissolved_ behind your back, it would lose its generality. e.g : _Limited Dissolve_ has options. Blender is quite UNIXy.. (I hope) .. tools that do _one_ thing, do it well, and can work with the others.

Comment: Of course your original SVG file has no zigzag lines going across - you created an outline and filled it with a color. But as soon as you convert it to a mesh, you cannot simply fill an outline with a color. There has to be a mesh, i.e. faces between those outlines, connecting vertices to buil a mesh. Since Blender not automatically makes one large N-gon, there are lots of faces created and the zigzag lines are the edges between them, where one face ends and another one begins.