# Export traced bitmap SVG from Inkskape and extrude+bevel

Tags: import, bevel, extrude, svg

This has been discussed many, many times. I am trying to understand/follow what's in:
[Extrude and bevel an imported svg curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve)

I also took a look at [Correct way to create an extruded mesh from a simple SVG shape? ie. Without creating insanely complex nonsense polygons?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249838/correct-way-to-create-an-extruded-mesh-from-a-simple-svg-shape-ie-without-crea) but I'm not sure that the whole curve-mesh conversion thing is what I want to do (based on other threads, too).

I don't really understand what's going on. I'm suffering the same problem, but I am not finding any "loose" vertices. If I hide everything except for one letter, select any vertex on that letter, and then select linked, I get the entire letter very clearly. Nothing seems "loose":

[image]

I am creating the SVG by tracing a bitmap in Inksape and then exporting. I don't think these are "loose" curves, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

If I set the bevel to some insanely tiny dimension (eg: .0000001), I then get a very stark "edge" in the center of the extrusion on the final object when a material is applied:

[image]

[Here is the SVG in question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/108IDVNhYPITzZyhshuqpBENtCK-0qe5N/view?usp=sharing)

Since I have the original bitmap, is there something I should do differently to export it from Inkskape to prevent this? Is mesh conversion and back the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

common mistake is to scale your curves in object mode, then when you bevel the object it will look huge... in the svg your logo is 10cm wide but default cube in blender is 200cm..! so you may want to scale it, but do it in edit mode

or even better, scale curves in your svg editor before exporting... it helps working in a bigger svg document size, like 500cm side, top left corner in Inkscape will be world origin in Blender

other than that see if you can find the font, those are difficult to trace..!

Comment: This _totally_ worked. I re-traced the bitmap and made the SVG 500cm x 500cm and now it imported well, extruded nicely, and beveled normally. Thank you so much!